# Front End User(bloger) turn on and off his comments

Tags: comments

I have a wordpress site with bunch of users, each of them having their own page with comments. I would like to implement a checkbox for users on the front end, to turn(toggle) on and off the comments. I know I can do it myself from the back end individually for each user page, but I need to let them to get their option.

In another words....is that possible to make a clone of that checkbox(from the admin panel) with the same functionality on the front end(on the user page)?

Can I have any idea on how to implement this?

I will appreciate any help for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this

```
//For update a page when use costum template
$post = get_the_ID();

 $my_post = array(
  'ID'           => $post,
  'comment_status' => 'open' // closed
);

// Update the post into the database
wp_update_post( $my_post );
```